# Active Admin - Same model for users and admins

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to have Active Admin do the backend for a site. I don't really want to have separate models for Users and AdminUsers though.

Can I have only admin users login to Active Admin if they have an is_admin flag in the Users model? If the users isn't an admin they should only be able to login to a simple control panel on the front of the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an `is_admin` flag to your `User` model, as you suggested. Then you can surround every admin option in your with an `is_admin?` condition and use some `before_filter :admin_required` in your controllers.

**application_controller.rb:**

```
# if user is not admin redirect to main page
def admin_required
  current_user.is_admin? || redirect_to("/")
end
```

**any_controller.rb:**

```
# Everybody can access show and index action, all others require admin flag set
before_filter :admin_required, :except => [:show, :index]
```

**any_view/show.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.is_admin? %>
  Hi Admin!
  Some cool admin stuff
<% else %>
  Hi User!
<% end %>
Stuff for everybody
```

Comment: Cool, so this would allow me to let only admins access Active Admin and let others login to a control panel elsewhere? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah but How do you create 2 separate signin forms (1 for an admin, 1 for a user) ? Problem explain here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346603/how-to-configure-activeadmin-routes-to-get-2-signin-pages-for-a-user-and-for-an

Answer (score 2):

Check out Active Admin's initializer file, `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`. In there you should see:

```
# == User Authentication
#
# Active Admin will automatically call an authentication 
# method in a before filter of all controller actions to 
# ensure that there is a currently logged in admin user.
#
# This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
# within the controller.
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
```

Change it from the default `:authenticate_admin_user!` to, for example, `admin_required` just like @amep said!