# How to configure ActiveAdmin routes to get 2 signin pages (for a user and for an admin) with 1 User model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, activeadmin

My project had 2 models: **AdminUser** and **User**.

I'd removed the **AdminUser** model (and db tables associated) and now I'm using my **User** model with an `admin?` method (I've had a boolean admin field in the users table)

ActiveAdmin documentation:

> You can skip the Devise user class all together by using the
>   skip-users flag:
>
> ```
> $> rails generate active_admin:install --skip-users
> ```
>
> NOTE: If you don’t use the default user settings, you will need to
>   configure the settings in config/intializers/active_admin.rb to suite
>   your needs.

Here's what I've found in the initializer:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

So, I've modified `application_controller.rb` as:

```
def authenticate_admin_user!
  render(:file => "#{Rails.root}/public/403.html", :status => 403, :layout => false) and return if user_signed_in? && !current_user.admin?
  authenticate_user!
end

def current_admin_user
  return nil if user_signed_in? && !current_user.admin?
  current_user
end
```

And in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config.merge(:class_name => 'User')
```

How can I configure ActiveAdmin to access admin section with the ActiveAdmin default path: `/admin`?

My objective is to have 1 User model, but 2 separate signin pages:

- **/users/sign_in** (default devise signin)
- **/admin** (ActiveAdmin signin)

For now, when I try to access **/admin**, I'm redirected to **/users/sign_in** page :-(

Thx for your advices...

Answer (score 0):

Since you skip generating new user model, replace any `admin_user` string in the generated stuff from ActiveAdmin to `user`. So instead of `:authenticate_admin_user!` replace it with `:authenticate_user!` and so on in migration files: instead of `admin_user_id` put `user_id` same for `admin_user_type` ... etc!