# How do I get my application.rb file to recognize current_user from active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am I am following this post:

[Active Admin - Same model for users and admins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268730/active-admin-same-model-for-users-and-admins)

and I have put

```
# if user is not admin redirect to main page
def admin_required
  current_user.is_admin? || redirect_to("/")
end
```

In my app/controllers/application_controller.rb

However I think I am missing something like

```
require 'activeadmin'
```

or something because I am getting the following error:

> undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Have I missed a step or something?

Comment: What are you using for authentication? If you are not using any external libraries, you will have to write your own method for current_user. The method will identify the current user based on your cookie/session credentials and call get create a model object for the corresponding user.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `current_user` method in `app/controller/application_controller.rb` and then make it available as a helper_method:

```
def current_user
  return unless session[:user_id]
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end
# Make current_user available in templates as a helper
helper_method :current_user
```